# AngularJS Google Oauth 400 Error Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Fragment not allowed

Tags: angularjs, oauth, kinvey

I am using Kinvey to handle Oauth on my AngularJS app, and it works just fine for Facebook, but when I try to sign in with Google, I am getting a 400 error:

**Error: invalid_request**

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Fragment not allowed: localhost:9000/#/login

Has anyone ever encountered this issue with Google Oauth and Angular? Any ideas on how I can get around it? The issue stems from the hash in the URL for Angular's routing.

Comment: Redirect uri must be the same as the one you entered in the dev console for your application  which is probably more like http  :// localhost:9000/#/login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` is called a `fragment identifier`. The error `Fragment not allowed:` means you must replace the `#` with an alternative, such as:

- localhost:9000/route/login

Then redirect with Kinvey:

```
req.request({uri: 'http://localhost:9000/route/login',
method: 'GET'},
function(error, response, body){
  response.statusCode = 302; 
  response.setHeader("Location", "/#/login");
  response.end();
  }
);
```

Here are some unrelated questions with similar issues:

- [Redirect to different page url in Node.js (Not in express or other frameworks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705024/1113772)
- [Redirecting client with NodeJS and Restify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613953/1113772)
- [URI encoding in Yahoo mail compose link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632335/1113772)
- [URL fragment missing from redirect URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810769/1113772)
- [Why URI-encoded ('#') anchors cause 404, and how to deal with it in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587744/1113772)